# MongoDB - How to get the latest messages from array of conversation id's

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which contains documents like the following:

```
{
    "conversation_id" : 1,
    "message_id" : 4, //Message number inside the conversation
    "text" : "..."
}
```

How to get the latest messages from array of conversation id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to match your conversation id in your array, perform a descending [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) according to `message_id` and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) taking the first item for each conversation :

```
var conversationIds = [1, 2];

db.conversations.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "conversation_id": {
            "$in": conversationIds
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "message_id": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$conversation_id",
        message_id: {
            $first: "$message_id"
        },
        document: {
            $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the document you would have to add a new property called `created`. When you then query a particular conversation you can sort it on the timestamp provided in `created`.

You should probably be able to sort on the `_id` as well as the `_id` goes up in some pre-defined way.

Comment: Now I can filter by the `conversation_id` and sort by the `message_id` to get the latest message of a certain conversation. But I have no idea how to get the latest messages of several conversation in one request.